# image in not coming up after after execution

Tags: c#, wpf

I can see the image while doing programming. But after execution I do not see the image. 
Do I need to add some tags?

```
<Window x:Class="DicomEditorInWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DicomImage Display" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="text button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"></Button>
    <Image Name="DicomImageDisplayer" Margin="332,124,0,0" Source="SampleImage.Jpg"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Remove margin from button and image.and try

Comment: thanks but it did not help.

Comment: Is the image part of the project or is it only located in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, i can see the image in the designer displayed above. but i dont see it same after execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers.

File must be added to the project, with the build action type of Resource.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your image is overlapped by the button. Try putting them in separate rows.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="*" />
        <RowDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="text button" Width="75"></Button>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Name="DicomImageDisplayer" Source="SampleImage.Jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

Or you can use a different container e.g. `StackPanel` or `DockPanel`.

Comment: i have removed button now and Added Grid.Row="1". ]

Comment: Did you add the row definitions? If so you can add both of them, just keep them on separate rows. That is the first one on Grid.Row="0" the other on Grid.Row="1"

Answer (score 0):

Just place your code inside a container, can be anything Grid,StackPanel and you should be able to see the image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this working in the codebehind not in the xaml, and remove the source from xaml

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/logo.png");
logo.EndInit();
finalImage.Source = logo;
```